# How to add dynamic class to angular 2,4 material tabs?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to add class to angular 4 material tabs. I didn't find any hell. Found no option. Tried this one

```html
<mat-tab-group disableRipple class="demo-tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="selectedDataTab($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
    <!-- <span *ngFor="let tab of gridTabName" [ngClass]="{'c2-hide': tab.recordId!=gridData.recordId}"> -->
        <mat-tab class="c2-upper-case" *ngFor="let tab of gridTabName" label="{{tab.name}}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem===tab}">
        </mat-tab>
    <!-- </span> -->
</mat-tab-group>
```

I even tried with a wrapper as the commented `span` element. But nothing is working. And by the way, the`[ngClass]` property does not work on `mat-tab`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what are you trying to do.. but as far as I can tell you are trying to append a new class to each tab without overwriting the other classes. Try this:

```
[class.c2-hide]="tab.recordId!=gridData.recordId"
```

in your code:

```
<mat-tab-group disableRipple class="demo-tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="selectedDataTab($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
        <mat-tab class="c2-upper-case" *ngFor="let tab of gridTabName" label="{{tab.name}}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem===tab}"
[class.c2-hide]="tab.recordId!=gridData.recordId"
>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Is it a permanent sorta comment or did u find a fix recently ?